# Validation is not applied for a foreign key dropdown

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

here is the beginning of the form in question:

```
 echo $this->Form->create('Event');
   echo $this->Form->input('Event.customer_id', array('label' => __('Customer'), 'empty'=>''));
        echo $this->Form->input('Event.service_id', array('label'=>__('Service'), 'empty'=>''));
```

Here is the validation rule for Event model:

```
'customer_id'=>array(
    'notEmpty'=>array(
        'rule'=>array('notEmpty'),
        'message'=> 'Vælg en kunde'
    )
)
```

And here is the relation if that is needed in any case:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Customer'=>array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
    )
    );
```

And there is no validation rules in Customer model on its id. I am trying to get it to work, but that rule is just not being fired, even though every other validation rule works.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think relation settings should not interrupt validation. You can try this:

```
'customer_id' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Vælg en kunde'
    )
)
```